# Display exponential values as float in Polars

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have some float columns in Polars df. Some values displays like `9.4036e15`. How I can display it with normal digital view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `.apply(str)`

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 9.4036e15]})
>>> df.select(pl.all().apply(str))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────────────────┐
│ a   | b                  │
│ --- | ---                │
│ str | str                │
╞═════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1   | 4.0                │
├─────┼────────────────────┤
│ 2   | 5.0                │
├─────┼────────────────────┤
│ 3   | 9403600000000000.0 │
└─────┴────────────────────┘
```

My first thought was to cast to a string - but it keeps the scientific notation:

```
>>> df.select(pl.all().cast(pl.Utf8))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ a   | b         │
│ --- | ---       │
│ str | str       │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   | 4.0       │
├─────┼───────────┤
│ 2   | 5.0       │
├─────┼───────────┤
│ 3   | 9.4036e15 │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: I don't think that would be the best or the right thing to do because if I have to perform any `groupby` aggregation on it like `sum` or `avg` then I would need to convert it back again to `numeric`. In `R ` there is `options(scipen = 999)` for such cases which I don't see it here. And I am also looking for the solution where I can do aggregation on these numbers and also don't show it as exponential.

Comment: @ViSa `pl.Config.set_fmt_float("full")` has since been added. There's also ongoing work for `.set_float_precision` [1] https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7378 [2] https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7475

Comment: thanks for letting me know about the new additions. Appreciate 'ur help !!!